# jQuery offset() not working as expected

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I'm completely new to stackoverflow please forgive me about formatting of code.
My issue is i've created a customized right click menu, which will be displayed on the 'tr'.All the 'tr' are dynamically generated and each right click ul is associated with each tr for different functionality. There is a problem with the offset(), whenever i right click on any of the tr i'm getting the menu position only relative to first tr. But the right click menus are different as i said earlier. Please help.

```
$('.cuz-menu').bind("contextmenu", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var posX = $(this).offset().left, posY = $(this).offset().top;
    $(this).find('.right-click').css({ "top": e.pageY - posY + "px", "left": e.pageX - posX -        85 + "px" }).show(0);
```

```
<tr class='right-content cuz-menu'>
         <td class="status ends-margin">
               <ul id=\"right-click\" class=\"right-click\">
                  <li>Diagram</li>
                  <li>Terminate</li>
                  <li>View Log</li>
               </ul>    
    <td class='rootProcess templates end-date'></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: It would really help if create a jsfiddle for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems like it would be with your calculation for the new top and left values; the difference between the `pageY` and the `offset().top` for each of the `<tr>` elements is going to be the same.

Let's say you have four `<tr>` elements, with a height of 50 pixels each. The top offset of the first row is 400 pixels, and you right-click exactly halfway down it. The `pageY` is going to be 425, the top offset is going be 400, so the new top value is 25.

Now you move your cursor 100 pixels down the screen, so you're halfway down the third row. You right-click on this row. The `pageY` is now 525, the top offset is now 500, but the new top value is still 25.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I understood the problem but is there any solution ?

Comment: @chatur Yes, change the way its calculated so you get the correct values for where you want it to be positioned. It's basic math, not a complex algorithm.

Comment: Hey thanks buddy i got the result. The position property for the <ul> right click menu was absolute and the parent for that was <tr> which was set relative. Thats the reason it wasn't taking up now i've moved the right click <ul> inside a div. It works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you want to position the menu at either the *TR position* or the *mouse position* -- not the difference between them, which will be approximately constant.

Mouse (event) position is often best, for right-click. Go slightly below & right:

```
var menu = $(this).find('.right-click');
menu.css({"top": (e.pageY+10)+"px", "left": (e.pageX+10)+"px"});
menu.show(0);
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment mate. This i tried few days back. It didn't work out because if the monitor size is increased, the right click position changes. (e.pageX position changes when the monitor size is changed). Could you please suggest me something else.

PS: I used <div> before using <tr> and the same code which i have pasted above was absolutely working fine. I was forced to remove <div> because it was affecting some of my peers codes.